# Returning unique mongodb documents using distinct not working

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Each message document has a messageTrackingId. I want to return all the messages, but exclude documents that have the same messageTrackingId. So for example, if I had 4 documents in my table and 3 of them have the same messageTrackingId value, then the Messages.find() should only return 2 documents.

I'm trying to use distinct to only return the unique documents so I don't get duplicates with the same messageTrackingId. Currently postman is returning no documents.

if I changed 
           `Messages.find({query}).distinct('messageTrackingId')`
to
   `Messages.find(query)`
then it returns all the recipientId's documents. but when I add distinct, I get no results.

```
app.get('/api/messages',(req, res, next)=>{
  query = {};
  inbox = false;
  messageId = false;
  if(req.query.recipientId){
    query = { recipientId: req.query.recipientId }
    inbox = true;

Messages.aggregate(// Pipeline
  [
      // Stage 1
      {
          $group: {
              _id: "$messageTrackingId",
              message : { $addToSet: '$message' },
              recipientId : { $addToSet: '$recipientId' },
              creator : { $addToSet: '$creator' },
              messageTrackingId : { $addToSet: '$messageTrackingId' },

          }
      },

      // Stage 2
      {
          $project: {
              _id: 1,
              message: { $arrayElemAt: ["$message", 0 ] },
              recipientId: { $arrayElemAt: ["$recipientId", 0 ] },
              creator: { $arrayElemAt: ["$creator", 0 ] },
              messageTrackingId: { $arrayElemAt: ["$messageTrackingId", 0 ] }
          }
      }

  ])
```

messages model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const messagingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  recipient: { type: String, required: true },
  recipientId: { type: String, required: true },
  message: { type: String, required: true },
  subject: { type: String, required: true },
  creationDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  messageTrackingId: { type: String }
  // readDate: { type: Date, required: true }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Messages", messagingSchema);
```

Comment: "if I had 4 documents in my table and 3 of them have the same messageTrackingId value, then the Messages.find() should only return 2 documents." - which of the 3 should get returned?

Comment: Only 2 documents would return in that scenario because 3 of the them have matching messageTrackingIds. I only need one document per messageTrackingId to reference that messageTrackingID.

Comment: So if 5 documents all have the same messageTrackingIds, just take the first one? Ordered by what property?

Comment: There's no preference on sorting. It doesn't matter which document it grabs with the same messageTrackingId as long as one of them returns. I just need that value to reference later when I do a GET for all related messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct` will return distinct **fields** which is not what you want.

You will need to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) and group by the messageTrackingId, then project grabbing the first message content etc you want:

Given sample data like:

```
{ "messageTrackingId" : 1, "message" : "hello" }
{ "messageTrackingId" : 1, "message" : "hello" }
{ "messageTrackingId" : 1, "message" : "bye" }
{ "messageTrackingId" : 2, "message" : "bye" }
{ "messageTrackingId" : 2, "message" : "bye" }
{ "messageTrackingId" : 1, "message" : "hello" }
```

**In MongoDB:**

```
db.getCollection("messages").aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$messageTrackingId",
            message : { $addToSet: '$message' }
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            message: { $arrayElemAt: ["$message", 0 ] }
        }
    },

]);
```

To use in mongoose, simply using the [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) function on your model:

**Using Mongoose**

```
const result = await Message.aggregate(// Pipeline
        [
            // Stage 1
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$messageTrackingId",
                    message : { $addToSet: '$message' }
                }
            },

            // Stage 2
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    message: { $arrayElemAt: ["$message", 0 ] }
                }
            },

        ]);
```

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS**

If you need to query for a given `messageTrackingId`, then add `$match` as the first stage of the pipeline:

```
const result = await Message.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: {
                    messageTrackingId: {$eq: 2}
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$messageTrackingId",
                    message : { $addToSet: '$message' }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    message: { $arrayElemAt: ["$message", 0 ] }
                }
            },

        ]);
```

Comment: I tried adding that to the pipeline, but I get aggregate is not a function? What am I doing wrong? I updated code above

Comment: With or without the Messages.find(query) I get the error. If I don't add that line, then I don't see how this would filter messages by the recipientId to make sure the user is getting their own messages too. I think I have to use $match and I added an additional line above, but I haven't gotten it right yet...

Comment: That example was for you to configure your aggregate query in MongoDB. I have updated the answer to show you how to simply run it off your Model.

Comment: To add match use the following in your first stage, before group of the pipeline:  `
            {
                $match: {
                    messageTrackingId: {$eq: 2}
                }
            },`

Comment: I added another line to group and project and I get the messageTrackingId to return now. I just don't understand why you put _id: "$messageTrackingId"? I updated code above

Comment: @user6680 $match in first as you want to limit the messages to only the ones you want to operate on. No point in working on all the other types that you are not interested in. $groups will group input documents by the _id expression. See the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)

Comment: match is working perfectly now. I add req.query.recipient id for it to match. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No prob, aggregation seems daunting at first but grab a coffee and read the docs. You will find it pretty clear and helpful.